# ractive-1.0.0-build9 parser error with interpolation within attribute

Tags: ractivejs

I'm in the process of upgrading to rev 1.0.0 build9. (Code was passing all tests with rev 0.7.3.)

In the template I have an element:

```
  <div on-click='complaint_{{id}}_edit_cancel()'/>
```

The mustache interpolation within that attribute is causing a parser error. I realize that there may be other ways to pass this variable to the event handler, but how should such interpolation be handled so as not to trigger a parser error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this was officially supported or if this was a side-effect of attribute parsing (which would make it a bug). As far as I know, Ractive only supports either a string or a JS expression as values of the [`on-*` directive](https://ractive.js.org/api/#on-42). Also, a function per `id` is a strange setup.

Anyways, expressions have full, unmustached access to data in the context. You can pass `i` as an argument of either [a method call or a proxy event](https://ractive.js.org/concepts/#expression-syntax_1).

```
// passes id as argument to a method
<div on-click="complaint_edit_cancel(id)"/>

// passes id as argument to an event, handled by ractive.on
<div on-click="['complaint_edit_cancel', id]"/>
```

Comment: thanks, you're right, the 'function per id' is strange and I'll need to refactor as you suggest. Thanks for taking the time to answer.